# My hello world React not appear

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I read the official tutorial of React and I try to create a basic hello world react app but I dont succeed.
I looked in the web and also here for an answer and I didnt find one.
Can you please tell me what I am missing and what I need to do?
The following is my html and javascript files:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, World</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="inputPhoneNumber.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div id="root" class="container">           
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What error are you getting in the console?

Comment: Thanks! There is no any error in the console

Comment: Alright. If you are loading `react` and `react-dom` from `unpkg`, you don't need them in your JS file. You can remove `import React from 'react'; import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`. Could you also try to write `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('h1', {}, 'Hello, World', document.getElementById('root'));` and see if that makes it work?

Comment: No, it still doesnt work

Comment: Could you try `text/javascript` instead of `text/jsx`? Is `inputPhoneNumber.js` the correct file name?

Comment: I tried text/javascript but it still doesnt work. InputPhoneNumber.js is the correct file name

Comment: `input` or `Input`?

Answer (score 1):

All you should need is the `react` and `react-dom` scripts like you already have, a root element like the `div` with id `root` you have, and a file which uses `ReactDOM` to render the topmost component into the root element.

**Example**

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement('h1', {}, 'Hello, World'),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It still doesnt work when i tried it in my visual studio code